# Can the topbar(crossbar) be lowered?

Tags: maintenance

Can the topbar(crossbar)on my fat bike be lowered?
I will ask a bicycle mechanic to do this job.

Comment: Not practically.  Usually would require cutting and welding, and the cost would be far more than a new bike.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by this?  Tell us about your end goal, rather than this specific path to get there.  We may have other ideas that help.

Comment: I want to achieve  a low  step fat bike

Answer (score 5):

**No**

The top tube is a structural element of the frame.  Cutting it off will destroy the bike, and welding it back together is not for the home mechanic.

Buy the frame you want rather than hacking up your current frame.

Comment: Bottom line is that this is not an adjustable part.  Get a properly sized bike.

Comment: There are a few bikes where it is adjustable, but this adds  considerable weight to the bike.

Comment: Thanks for your replies....So where can I buy a low step, fat bike frame,for 26x4.0 tyres?   Do they exist even?

Comment: @PETE you should try your local bike shop, or search the web.  We can't tell you what's near to you.

Comment: Ok but if you hear of a shop that will make a low step fat frame and ship it to Vietnam, please  me let me know...thanks !!

Comment: @pete  https://www.google.com/search?q=bicycle+frame+builder+site%3Avn